# Відмінювання слова "снігур"

Tags: правопис, відмінювання

Як відмінюється слово снігур?
Чи правильно я вважаю, що це іменник другої відміни твердої групи (так подано у новому правописі)? І в такому разі в орудному відмінку має бути "снігуром"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Як за [новим правописом](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf) (§ 67), так і за [попередньою його версією](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par45) (§ 45), ***снігур*** - це справді іменник чол. роду другої відміни твердої групи. За оновленим правописом (§ 85):

> В орудному відмінку однини іменники другої відміни мають закінчення -ом, -ем (-єм) і -ям, -им.
>
> 1. Закінчення -**ом** мають усі іменники чол. та середн. роду твердої групи [...]

А значить в орудному відмінку *снігур* має закінчення ***-ом***.

До речі, Правопис 2019 р. зауважує (§ 67), що іменники *звір, комар, снігур* у називному відмінку множини мають закінчення м’якої групи: *звірі, комарі, снігурі*. Як правило, іменники другої відміни твердої групи в цьому випадку мають закінчення *-и* (*дуб - дуби, двір - двори*). *Звір, комар, снігур* тут виступають як винятки.

Однак жодних винятків для іменника *снігур* в орудному відмінку однини правопис не подає. А отже цей іменник мав би відмінюватись тут за загальним правилом - з закінченням *-ом*.

На сайті slovnyk.ua ми [бачимо](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80) саме такий зразок відмінювання:

[image: om]

Щоправда, ["Словники України" on-line](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) чомусь подають зразок відмінювання *снігура* із *-ем* в орудному відмінку:

[image: em]

У будь-якому разі, в літературі можна частіше натрапити на форму *снігуром* (уривки з [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1368&bih=625&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQAuBawnBHvjV-l8aadBEY-zWz3pQ%3A1573911103275&ei=P_rPXd3BEPKwrgSjwZm4Dg&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%22&oq=%22%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15616.15923.0.16654.2.2.0.0.0.0.110.215.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Db0Z0T4Znbc)):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Ще більше результатів є з відмінюванням прізвища *Снігур* як *Снігуром*. Якщо шукати в Google Books *"снігурем"*, то результатів [бачимо](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1368&bih=625&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNS8NLEptzzCLZewBddhuWEHRkYOzw%3A1573911050413&ei=CvrPXdz1GJKNrwTuyb-wAQ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%22&oq=%22%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...51026.51267.0.51482.2.2.0.0.0.0.139.238.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.a8JsGdu_URc) значно менше.

Comment: Про всяк: Словники України наверху мають «_Здійснюється лексикографічне опрацювання ІЛС "Словники України" відповідно до вимог нового правопису. Дякуємо за розуміння!_». Відповідь чудова!